# Multiline alignment of Matplotlib legend LaTeX text

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code yields the figure below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = np.random.rand(100)
ys = np.random.rand(100)
r, p = 0.930, 1e-5
label = '$T_m$\n$\\rho = %.3f, p = %.1e$'%(r, p)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(xs, ys, label=label)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

**I would like the legend text centered, i.e. the `'$T_m$'` centered in the first line**.  I've tried using the `str.format` mini-language with various things like

```
label = '{0:{x}^25}\n{1:.3f}, {2:.1e}'.format('$T_m$', r, p, x=' ')
```

which I thought would work because the following gives

```
>>> print ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
([<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x7fa099286590>],
 [u'     $\\Delta T_{m}$      \n$\\rho=0.930, p=1.2 \\times 10^{-5}$'])
```

but the whitespace gets stripped in the label.  I can't use any latex space (`'\;'` or `'\\mbox{}'`) for the fill character because they are multiple characters.  I also tried using the `multialignment='center'` keyword in various places, but it is not a valid kwarg to `ax.legend`.

**How can I get centered multiline alignment in my legend text?**  Ultimately, I will several legend handles where label text can have either more characters in the second line (shown here) or more characters in the first line (opposite as shown here).

I am using python 2.7.6 and matplotlib 1.4.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you figured out yourself the key is the `multialignment` argument. However, it is not an argument to the `legend` function, but merely a propery of [Text Atrists](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text). So the trick is to save a handle of the legend and then set this propery for each text element:

```
leg = ax.legend()
for t in leg.texts:
    t.set_multialignment('center')
```

Result:

[image]